# How to give password to pg_dump without prompt?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, subprocess, pg-dump

I have the following Python code that works locally to generate a dump.
I would like to dockerise it without having the prompt password for the database connection when I use pg_dump command and also I don't know what will I give in the dockerfile instead of postgres_bin = r"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"

```
import os
import paramiko
import subprocess

postgres_bin = r"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"
dump_file = "database_dump.sql"

with open(dump_file, "w") as f:
    result = subprocess.call([os.path.join(postgres_bin, "pg_dump"), "-Fp", "-d", "XXX", "-U", "XXX", "-h", "XXX", "-p", "XXX"], stdout=f)

transport.close()
```

This code works locally. I would like to have the same code working without having to give a password in a prompt that I have locally.

How can I do that ?

##### ---- UPDATE ----

I updated my code below. This code works with a prompt. But When I uncomment the ligne with "-w" and env={'PGPASSWORD': 'secret'} I have the error that hostname can't be translate : Unknown server error.

```
import os
import paramiko
import subprocess

print("Import has been done !")

postgres_bin = r"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"
dump_file = "database_dump.sql"

with open(dump_file, "w") as f:
        result = subprocess.call([
                os.path.join(postgres_bin, "pg_dump"), 
                "-Fp", 
                "-d", 
                "anonymedev", 
                "-U", 
                "pgsqladmin", 
                "-h", 
                "hostname", 
                "-p", 
                "32045", 
                # '-w'
                ], 
                # env={'PGPASSWORD': 'secret'},
                stdout=f
                )
```

Comment: You can use the `PGPASSWORD` or `PGPASSFILE` environment variables as described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I think you right and I not used it well. Do you have an example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PGPASSWORD` or `PGPASSFILE` environment variables as described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).

For example, to dump the database "example" as user "postgres" with password "secret", I can write:

```
PGHOST=127.0.0.1 \
PGUSER=postgres \
PGPASSWORD=secret \
PGDATABASE=example \
pg_dump
```

I can store the password in a file instead of using the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable; in that case, we need to format the file as described in "[The Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)":

```
echo 127.0.0.1:5432:example:postgres:secret
```

And then reference that file with the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable:

```
PGPASSFILE=pgpass \
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres example
```

---

If you are running `pg_dump` from Python, then in order to set an environment variable you need to set keys in `os.environ`, or use the `env` parameter to `subprocess.call`.

Using the `env` parameter sets the environment for that single `subprocess.call` invocation, and you must explicitly include existing environment variables if you want them visible in the child process:

```
with open(dump_file, "w") as f:
    result = subprocess.call(
        [
            os.path.join(postgres_bin, "pg_dump"),
            "-Fp",
            "-d",
            "XXX",
            "-U",
            "XXX",
            "-h",
            "XXX",
            "-p",
            "XXX",
        ],
        env=os.environ | {'PGPASSWORD': 'secret'},
        stdout=f,
    )
```

(Note that the [`dict` union syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/) here requires Python 3.9 or later).

Alternately, you can update `os.environ`, which will make the variable available to all subsequent subprocesses:

```
os.environ['PGPASSWORD'] = 'secret'

with open(dump_file, "w") as f:
    result = subprocess.call(
        [
            os.path.join(postgres_bin, "pg_dump"),
            "-Fp",
            "-d",
            "XXX",
            "-U",
            "XXX",
            "-h",
            "XXX",
            "-p",
            "XXX",
        ],
        stdout=f,
    )
```

Comment: Before "with open..." in my code I added PGPASSWORD=secret but connection doesn't work.

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I added this : env={'PGPASSWORD': 'secret'} but now I have the error that hostname can't be translate : Unknown server error. It works when I don't add  env={'PGPASSWORD': 'secret'}. So I don't know where the problem comes from.

Comment: The host is a remote PGAAS host

Comment: That could be an error in your code, but to diagnose that I would have to see the actual code with your recent changes. Maybe you could update your question and add it?

Comment: I updated my question with code I used with your answer

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake! Setting `env` on `subprocess.call` *overrides* the process environment, so you must explicitly include existing environment variables. I've updated the answer here with two alternatives.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried the two possibilities. First one throw an error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: '_Environ' and 'dict'. Second possibility works ! Do you have any advice of how I can secure it more about the password ? My final goal is to put this code in flask app and dockerise it. Maybe hard coded password is not okay

Comment: Certainly a hardcoded password is a bad idea. A common solution is to read the password from the environment -- this way it can be read from a `.env` provided to the app, or to `docker` or `docker-compose`, or via `docker run -e PGPASSWORD="..."`, etc.